# Session.connect: java.net.ConnectException

Tags: java, linux, sftp, phpstorm

I am new to this subject .

I'm trying to connect to server using [VMware](http://www.vmware.com/) and the server side is Linux - ubuntu.
when i want to connect with Phpstorm to server i get this error :

> Connection to '192.168.48.132' failed. Session.connect:
>   java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

i checked IP ADDRESS ... (it works) and also disable firewall in Ubuntu

am i missing something ?

Comment: 1) Where you are trying to connect to it **from** (what screen/functionality) 2) The error message indicates that either something still blocks connections (e.g. firewall -- could be even on your end) .. or required port is closed (nothing is listening on that port). 3) Try connecting with `telnet` to that IP:port if you believe it's java's/PhpStorm's fault.

Comment: @LazyOne the command i tried in cmd on win 8 is : telnet 192.168.48.132 22  
is it true ? if it's true ... i get this error :could not open the connection on port 22

Comment: i'm trying to connect from win 8 to linux

Comment: Double check the IP. It's either IP or port is still blocked (assuming that firewall is out of question). In any case -- it has nothing to do with actual PhpStorm itself. Since you are trying to connect to SSH, try `putty` program first (SSH client for windows, free). Once you will be able to connect using that specialized program, you should be able to connect with IDE as well.

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu, you may try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install openssl-sever
```

I have met this problem just now. Check if you have install OpenSSH-server on your linux-server.

You may also try connect linux with other tools, like `putty and xshell` and so on, the error mostly like not due to phpstrom.

If other tools can connect to linux, you may try to `close firewall`

```
$ ufw disable
```

Your linux network connection ip should be set to static